# Laravel eloquent class variable documentation

Tags: php, variables, laravel, documentation, eloquent

I'm building a website with laravel and had some trouble with the documentation of the variables in an eloquent class. I've seen that the eloquent class uses an attributes-array to store all the variables. I'd like to document the available attributes in my classes so I can easily generate documentation and have code-completion with descriptions.
I tried declaring the variables in the classes for documentation. I've tried declaring them public, but then the attributes-array isn't used anymore which is necessary. Declaring them protected works for the attributes-array, but the declared variables aren't used and the documentation and declarations aren't available in other files for code-completion, suggestions and descriptions.
I also would like to avoid getter and setters.
Is there a convenient way of documenting those variables in laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not Laravel specific but PHPDoc with Netbeans works well for documentation and autocomplete.

Comment: I'm working in Netbeans and am using php doc-syntax to document my code for autocompletion and documentation. It are those attributes which are the problem because those are managed in the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can document member variables with `@property type $variable`:

```
/**
 * @property string $foo
 * @property int $bar
 */

class MyModel extends Eloquent {

}
```